# Function Not Properly Returning Array Though Can See in Debug.Print

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

I am writing an Excel VBA function that returns an array to use in other functions. When I test out the function `GenerateBlendedReturnSeries` in my Excel Sheet and use `ctlr-shift-enter` to see the full result, the entire array is all zeros. Strangely, however, when I check `Debug.Print (BlendedReturnSeriesArray(300, 1))`, the proper non-zero value is returned. Why is the function unable to properly return this result? I array being returned is 329 x 1 and contains `""` values in rows when the multiplication/addition in the `for loop` returns an error.

```
Function GenerateBlendedReturnSeries(AccountID1 As String, Account1Proportion As Double, _
     Optional ByVal AccountID2 As String, Optional ByVal Account2Proportion As Double, _
     Optional ByVal AccountID3 As String, Optional ByVal Account3Proportion As Double) As Variant 'Vs. As Double()

' CODE IN BETWEEN

Dim BlendedReturnSeriesArray As Variant
    ReDim BlendedReturnSeriesArray(ArraySize, 1)

    Debug.Print (ArraySize)

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To UBound(BlendedReturnSeriesArray)

        BlendedReturnSeriesArray(i, 1) = _
          Account1PeriodReturnSeriesArray(i, 1) * Account1Proportion _
        + Account2PeriodReturnSeriesArray(i, 1) * Account2Proportion _
        + Account3PeriodReturnSeriesArray(i, 1) * Account3Proportion
        'Debug.Print (BlendedReturnSeriesArray(i, 1))
        'Debug.Print (i)

    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0

    Debug.Print (BlendedReturnSeriesArray(300, 1))

    GenerateBlendedReturnSeries = BlendedReturnSeriesArray 'BlendedReturnSeriesArray

End Function
```

Comment: Where does `ArraySize` come from?  Or `Account1PeriodReturnSeriesArray` etc ?

Comment: `ArraySize` comes from the `Rows.Count` of the Range that you get from an `Index,Match` using the `AccountID`’s. `Account1PeriodReturnSeriesArray` is a `Variant` of dimensions `ArraySize` x 1 that comes from the Range `Account1PeriodReturnsSeries`, which you get from an `Index,Match` using the `AccountID`’s. I omitted this code since as the `Debug.Print` shows, the final array is working as expected except when I try to return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you do this

```
ReDim BlendedReturnSeriesArray(1 To ArraySize, 1 To 1)
```

or you're using `Option Base 1` (never a good idea), your return array will be sized as (0 to ArraySize, 0 to 1), so likely you're only seeing the first "column" of the array (the zero index) on your worksheet. If you expand the formula to cover two columns you'll see the numbers you're missing.